# What is the bar code on a Ryanair online ticket?

Tags: tickets, ryanair

I have booked Ryanair one way air tickets for my parents from Malpensa (Italy) to Stansted (UK).
When they walked to the check-in counter the ground staff asked to show a bar code on the ticket, but unfortunately we didn't get any bar code on the online ticket. Then they wanted my parents to purchase a new ticket; finally they informed my parents that your time is out so you better find another flight. Once my parents called me I was shocked.
Please let me know what is this bar code?

Now they have to wait another 12 hours at the airport for the next flight and their is no one advising them how to change their ticket for their next flight. All the officers want them to buy a new ticket and they ask my parents to inquire about the previous tickets online.

Now they got stuck at Malpensa airport.
Can anyone advice me how to change their previous ticket to travel on the next flight?

Comment: An electronic ticket isn’t the same as a boarding pass, which includes the bar code required for scanning at check in and security. The bar code looks like a block of straight lines (you see them on food packages, clothes tags etc) and contains data on the booking eg the passenger’s full name, flight record finder, arrival and departure airports, the airline you're flying, and frequent-flier number. Ryanair requires all passengers to checkin online and print their boarding pass https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_1379164564

Comment: @Traveller Ryanair's boarding passes are visually different from those found in retail stores. They either use Aztec code (mobile) or pdf417 (paper) on their boarding passes. You can quickly Google some examples or if anyone is interested in the composition have a play with: https://shooshx.github.io/BoardingBarcode/

Answer (score 1):

An electronic ticket isn’t the same as a boarding pass, which includes the bar code required for scanning at check in and security. The bar code looks like a block of straight lines (you see them on food packages, clothes tags etc) and contains data on the booking eg the passenger’s full name, flight record finder, arrival and departure airports, the airline you're flying, and frequent-flier number. Ryanair requires all passengers to checkin online and print their boarding pass https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_1379164564
You won’t be able to change to an alternative flight free of charge. It looks like your parents had checked in but didn’t have valid Boarding Passes and there was insufficient time for the airline to re-issue them with an alternative form of Boarding Pass. Ryanair Terms&Conditions state that for travel on a later flight, passengers will be required either to make and pay for a new reservation or to pay the Missed Departure Fee (only available to passengers less than 40 minutes before and up to 1 hour after the flight departure time). It doesn’t sound like Ryanair were particularly helpful to your parents in this situation - the airline is not renowned for its customer service. You can complain about this here https://contactform.ryanair.com/?cr=4-0&lg=en&id=43&compr=Airport+-+Check-in%2FBoarding+Gate%2FTravel+Documents